# Highcharts pie animation: disable scaling

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts, pie-chart

Good day.
How to edit pie chart init\update animation?
I want to remove scaling effect (from 0 to 100% size) and stay only radial effect.

I did't find advanced documentation to

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.animate = function(init) {
```

Here is forked official jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yyb8gnhd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the scaling effect, comment out the `r` attribute that is set to go from `0` to `args.r`. Here is the working [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5eh9j14c/)

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.animate = function(init) {
  var series = this,
    points = series.points;

  if (!init) {
    Highcharts.each(points, function(point, index) {
      var graphic = point.graphic,
        args = point.shapeArgs;

      if (graphic) {
        graphic.attr({
          // r: 0,
          start: 0,
          end: 0
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
          graphic.animate({
            // r: args.r,
            start: args.start,
            end: args.end
          }, series.options.animation);
        }, 100);
      }
    });

    this.animate = null;
  }
};
```